# Displaying data from database with ConnectionRequest on IOS simulator and device

Tags: ios, codenameone

coding with codenameone, I need to pull and refresh before data got with ConnectionRequest display on ios screen. Can someone help me displaying the data without pull and refresh?

Comment: What have you tried or what isn't working?

Comment: If you used the `addPullToRefresh(Runnable task)` API, you can simply run the `Runnable task` to get a refresh when you want it (simulating a pull to refresh without actually touching the screen). For the same reason, if you are using an `InfiniteContainer`, maybe the API `refresh()` can be useful.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answers. I'm trying to display my data in a BoxLayout Container which is added to a BorderLayout Form. On Android Simulator and device data are displayed well but on iOS I'm obliged to touch the screen or pull before displayiny contents. that's the issue I'm facing

Comment: I'm guessing that you added the data after the form is shown and didn't revalidate. This might be triggered by a race condition that only manifests in the iOS port.